# Scripting for file management with a very large amount of files

Tags: bash, macos, perl, find, rename

I have a three OSX machine setup that was using syncthing to keep shared drives synchronized remotely.  Someone made some mistakes and a lot of files ended up getting renamed.

So all throughout this drive I have situations where there's a file of size 0KB named,for example, `file.jpg` and another file with real size named 
`file.sync-confilct201705-4528.jpg`.  I need to search the entire drive recursively and while I find a file with the sync-conflict string in it, check to see if there is the same file without the 'sync-conflict' string along with a size of 0KB.  If there is, I need to rename the sync-conflict file to overwrite the 0KB file.

I have considered tackling this with a bash script or a Perl script.  Using bash I think just using the 'find' command with -regex would get me started but I don't really know how to process the results and run the next find test.  I am studying and working on it.

Same problem with Perl. I can get through the first step using File::Find:find and select what I need using regex to filter out the files, but there again I am stuck getting to the next step, which would be finding the original file in the same directory and performing the necessary file move function.

In both of these cases I am willing to put in the time to figure it out, but I wonder what the caveats will be?  Can both of these scenarios handle recursing a large number of files without exception?  Is there perhaps a better approach anyone can recommend?

Comment: My first suggestion is to make a backup before you start anything.

Comment: It would probably be easier to first search for zero size files and check if there is a corresponding conflict file.  That may not completely resolve the problem, but would be a good first step.  Then if you have remaining conflict files, compare the content and remove the conflict file if they match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One good tool in Perl for this is [File::Find::Rule](http://search.cpan.org/~rclamp/File-Find-Rule-0.34/lib/File/Find/Rule.pm).

Find all `sync-conflict` files, then test whether corresponding files exist and are zero size

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use FindBin qw($RealBin);
use File::Copy qw(move);
use File::Find::Rule;

my $dir = shift || '.';  # top of hierarchy to search (from command line, or ./)

my @conflict_files = File::Find::Rule
    ->file->name('*sync-conflict*.jpg')->in($dir);

foreach my $conflict (@conflict_files)
{
    my ($file) = $conflict =~ m|(.*)\.sync-conflict|;
    $file .= '.jpg';

    if (-z "$RealBin/$file") {
        print "Rename $conflict to $file\n"
        #move($conflict, $file) or warn "Can't move $conflict to $file: $!";
    }
 }
```

This builds the file's name `file` for each `file.sync-conflict` file and applies `-z` [file test (-X)](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html), which tests for both existence and zero size. Then it renames the file using the core [File::Copy](https://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html).

Note that file-test operators need the full path while `File::Find::Rule` returns the path relative to the `$dir` it searches. I use `$RealBin` provided by [FindBin](http://perldoc.perl.org/FindBin.html), which is the path to the directory where the script was started with all links resolved,  to build the full path for `-z`.

Uncomment the `move` line after sufficient testing (and with having made a backup first).

The code makes some assumptions about file names, please adjust as needed.
The `$dir` supplied on the command line is expected to be relative to the script's directory.

Comment: @J.P.  I added a paragraph of explanation of `$RealBin` in the code (file-test operators need full path while `File::Find::Rule` provides a relative path, so when we use what the module returned we must amend it to the full path for `-z`).  It's the same thing I've written as a comment to your other question but I don't know whether you saw it, thus this note.  Please let me know if anything else pops up.

Comment: @J.P Please do let me know if code explanations would be useful.

Comment: Thank you, I grasp what you are saying.  I've taken your direction and put together something that works well so far.  I would be happy to post it.  What is the correct approach?   Should I just edit the original question and post the updated code?

Comment: @J.P.  Thanks for asking!  No, that's one thing you don't want to do.  Most of these questions get visited by other people later and it is good the keep the question as it was initially, so that the answers still make sense.  Then it may be a useful page, and some get a lot of visits long after the question was asked.

Comment: @J.P.  If there are things in the code that don't work as you expect them to then by all means post it as another question.  Even if things "work" but you don't know why (and have other expectations of that code) it may be a perfectly good question to ask. If it all works fine and you want a comment on your code, that's what [Code-Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)  is for (one of StackExchange sites).  I think that their criteria are a little more stringent though.

Comment: @J.P.  Another way may be to post it as your own answer. It is legitimate to post your own answers, and this is a good idea when you don't get a full answer but you figure it out yourself.  It is not common to post it just so, but I'll be very happy to look over it; let me know with a comment if you do that.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function to fix the name:

```
$ function fixname() { file="$1"; newname=$( echo "$file" | sed "s/sync-conflict.*\.jpg$/.jpg/" );  if [ -f "$newname" -a ! -s "$newname" ]; then mv "$file" "$newname"; fi; }
```

Or, spread out a bit:

```
function fixname() {
    file="$1"
    newname=$( echo "$file" | sed "s/sync-conflict.*\.jpg$/.jpg/" )
    # If empty file exists
    if [ -f "$newname" -a ! -s "$newname" ]; then
        mv "$file" "$newname"
    fi
}
```

Export the function:

```
$ export -f fixname
```

Run find to execute the function:

```
$ find . -type f -name \*sync-conflict\*.jpg -exec bash -c 'fixname {}' bash \;
```

Caveat: It will not work with spaces or funky characters in the filenames.

Answer (score 0):

`find` is great. But as you've noted, you need more.

What `find` gets you in this scenario is the ability to search recursively and match certain patterns. As it happens as of Bash version 4, you can do that right in the shell.

(Note that macOS ships with bash version 3, so for this solution, you'll need to install bash 4 from [Macports](http://www.macports.org/), [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) or [Fink](http://www.finkproject.org/).)

```
$ shopt -s globstar nullglob
$ for file in **/*sync-confilct2017*.*; do echo mv -v "$file" "${file%sync-conf*}${file##*.}"; done
mv -v file.sync-confilct201705-4528.jpg file.jpg
mv -v foo/bar.sync-confilct201705-4528.ext foo/bar.ext
```

You can remove the `echo` to actually run the `mv` command.

The way this works is that the double asterisk, `**`, is treated by bash like a `*` that recurses. We're using parameter expansion to strip the parts of the filename we want in order to construct the "target" filename.