# find -exec cant find local function "find: Log: No such file or directory"

Tags: bash, find, exec

i have a piece of code that should print all files in specific dir. i use find exec for this:

```
find ${_di} -type f -print -exec Log "$(stat -c%y {}) - {}" \;
```

Where log is function of mine defines in same file. 
But id does not work and i get error message:

> "find: Log: No such file or directory".

Why? What is wrong in this piece of code?

Comment: Where is Log placed and does it have "executable" attribute? Maybe it should be ./Log ?

Comment: The find will be spawned as a separate process and so will not be able to access functions stored within your script. The exec functionality of find will only be able to execute files within the file system and not functions within specific files.

Answer (score 2):

Function can't be used in -exec however `bash -c` can be used as command.
Slightly modified to using `+` as -exec command terminator and `{}` last to allow to reduce the number of bash processes spawned.

```
find ${_di} -type f -print -exec bash -c "$(typeset -f Log)"$'\n''for arg; do Log "$(stat -c%y "$arg") - $arg"; done' -- {} +
```

the argument `--` can be replaced by anything else it is used for `$0` argument of shell.

```
bash -c 'echo $0' hello
```

Maybe `-printf "%TY-%Tm-%Td %TT - %p\n"` option could achieve the same result, more efficiently without launching other process.

Also using echo may be less safe than using find `-print` option, considering the following use case.

```
touch file.$'\e#8'
find . -type d ! -name . -prune -o -name file'*' -print
find . -type d ! -name . -prune -o -name file'*' -exec echo {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to export the function, and then, as Nahuel says, run bash in the `-exec`:

```
$ export -f Log

$ find ${_di} -type f -exec bash -c 'Log "$(stat -c%y {}) - {}"' bash \;
```

Comment: Have you tried? it doesn't work correct options `-exec bash -c 'Log "$(stat -c%y $1) - $1"' - {} \;`

Comment: I cannot try your `Log` function, because you did not post it.

Comment: See how I did it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44424514/scripting-for-file-management-with-a-very-large-amount-of-files/44425140#44425140

Comment: I'm not the user who asked the question and i created my own `Log() { echo $@;}`

Comment: You're right -- forgot to quote the command sent to bash.  Fixed.  Thanks.

Comment: ok I didn't thnik to replace directly the filename inside the script command because this works only by launching a shell process for each file which is not very efficient, note: I've updated my answer with -printf option which avoids launching new process

Comment: "Log" is a function in the same bash script, i don't want to export it,

Comment: `export`ing a variable or function only allows child processes to use it, not all processes.